# Elasticsearch exeact match on analyzed field of integers

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I want to find exact matches on a (analyzed string) field in ES. All values are integers but mapped as strings. I, unfortunately, cannot change the mapping and using

```
query: {
  match: {
    fieldName: '1234'
  }
}
```

also gives me 0 hits.
I cannot figure out if it's the standard analyzer working in a bizarre way when the mapping is

```
index: {
 type: {
  properties: {
   fieldName: {
    type: string
   }
  }
 }
}
```

and data is

```
{fieldName: '12345'}
```

or there is something in the match query that I'm missing.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your quotations for the fieldNames value from ticks `'` to quotes `"`. Trying your query will the correct quotes returns the expected results on my end.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "fieldName": "1234"
        }
    }
}
```